# Gradient calculation for timeseries data in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that can return me the gradient from a line of best fit with the below `dataframe`

After going through several resources google, i am still uncertain how this is suppose to be done.

I understand that the formula for line of best fit is calculated as: `y = mx + b`. With the dependent variable (y) is set to be the `foos`, and the independent variable (x) is set to be the `DateTime`.

**Dataframe**

```
DateTime                    foos
2019-06-02 11:10:00.000000  0.01693508247952
2019-06-02 11:09:00.000000  0.5880636280067069
2019-06-02 11:08:00.000000  0.039372713999924
2019-06-02 11:07:00.000000  0.0695437258183455
2019-06-02 11:05:00.000000  1.5659431108801645
2019-06-02 11:04:00.000000  0.557622107242239
2019-06-02 11:03:00.000000  1.636076943844067
2019-06-02 11:02:00.000000  0.95229579554872
2019-06-02 11:01:00.000000  4.140446615946458
2019-06-02 11:00:00.000000  1.9773540525390418
2019-06-02 10:59:00.000000  0.4339180765629633
2019-06-02 10:58:00.000000  0.9779139666335716
...
```

How/what can i use to be able to return the gradient value for the data with the time series?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`pandas.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand how `diff` will provide me with the gradient?

Comment: By gradient, do you mean the difference between two consecutive points? Or the difference divided by the time (in some frequency units?)